# ¿Esta discusión en «La Casa de Papel» es un juego de palabras? ¿Por qué relaciona "Aikido" con aire acondicionado o palitos de chocolate?

Tags: identificación-de-término, cultura-de-masas, significado-en-contexto

Miraba «*La Casa de Papel*» (El episodio es «Aikido») y aparece una discusión que no entiendo. Aquí está mi transcripción, pero Nairobi habla muy muy rápido en esta parte, así es posible que no sea perfecta:

> [Profesor] ¿Sabéis lo qué es el «Aikido»?
>
> [Denver] Yo sé, un aire acondicionado.
>
> [Nairobi] No, no, no. Son los palitos estos de chocolate que no sirven ni de merienda ni de tentempié.

Y mi traducción al inglés es así:

> [Profesor] Do you know what "Aikido" is?
>
> [Denver] I know, an air conditioner.
>
> [Nairobi] No, no, no. It's those sticks of chocolate that serve as neither a refreshment nor a snack.

Aparte de «merienda», confío que mi traducción sea suficientemente correcta, pero no entiendo por qué lo dicen.  *Pienso que* Denver y Nairobi están haciendo un juego de palabras porque hay un juego de palabras parecido en inglés.  En este juego, los jugadores dan una definición de una palabra como la primera palabra o, a veces, la última palabra.

**¿Esto es un juego de palabras? ¿Qué me perdí? Y ¿qué son «los palitos estos de chocolate que no sirven ni de merienda ni de tentempié»?**

Comment: Seguramente no se refiere a los palitos de chocolate en sí, sino a la marca bajo la que se comercializan, que es "Mikado" y que suena parecida a "Aikido".

Comment: Creo que @Charlie tiene razón:  https://www.golosinasysnacks.com/11735-medium_default/lu-mikado-chocolate-negro-24-estuches-de-39g.jpg.

Comment: No, it's those chocolate sticks that are no good for snacking on or holding you over. [tenertepié: a snack that stops you fainting from hunger, keeps you on your feet]. My first post didn't work, this is right now. In Spanish: servir para algo means: to be good for something. No one is serving anything. :)

Comment: sorry: tentenpié comes from: tente en pié OR tenerte en pié. stay standing up,literally. to hold you over=to help you wait until a meal is served, AKA tide you over.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Creo que las referencias son [*Daikin*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daikin) y [*Mikado*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocky) (como [dice @Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/esta-discusi%C3%B3n-en-la-casa-de-papel-es-un-juego-de-palabras-por-qu%C3%A9-relacion#comment59480_32907)):

- Daikin es una marca japonesa de electrodomésticos que comercializa aires acondicionados.
- Mikado es el nombre comercial en España de una golosina consistente en un palito de galleta cubierto de chocolate.

[image]

Comment: How does this answer the question at all?There is no joke and it can be translated without knowing the brand.

Comment: @Lambie - Save yourself the aggravation.  Write a supplementary answer.  By the way I'd go for "useless" although "good for nothing" is also not bad.

Comment: @Lambie - there is a joke, the joke is the characters don't know what aikido is and mistake it for similar-ish sounding Japanese words they are familiar with. Yes you can translate the dialogue itself without knowing the references (as OP did), but without knowing the references you're not likely to get the humour, hence the question. I'm struggling to see how your don't think this answers the questions at the end of the post...

Comment: @ukemi - Also a great explanation.  I wonder if we could call these malapropisms (from Mrs. Malaprop)?

Answer (score -2):

Aikido es marca de palitos de chocolate, como suena a japonés dicen aire acondicionado, como pudiera haber dicho lavadora u otro electrodoméstico, simplemente porque suena a japonés. No hay otro juego de palabras, sino que JapOn tiene fama de tener buena electrónica y por lo tanto electrodomésticos

Comment: Como se menciona en los comentarios, SÍ hay una relación entre aikido y el aire acondicionado (daikin) y los palitos (mikado). Aparte de que las tres son de origen japonés, también comparten "fonemas" (entrecomillo pues no soy experto en identificarlos exacta y canónicamente): daikin y aikido comparten aiki; aikido y mikado comparte ik y do. El juego de palabras se pierde si ponemos alguna otra cosa típicamente japonesa: "Sí, es pescado crudo". O cualquier electrodoméstico "No, es una lavadora".

Comment: @RubioRic - Bien explicado.  Es como el "alemán" de Charlie Chaplin en The Great Dictator.